# What/which event(s) fires off when the screen-size changes?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Is the browser re-rendered whenever the browser size changes? For example whenever you resize the browser. If that is the case then which events are getting triggered from that and is it possible to trigger them through javascript?

Context: I have a very odd bug on my website that only appears on mobile devices (and only on iPhones). But whenever I change the orientation back and forth from vertical to horizontal to the bug is fixed. Therefore, as a last resort, I thought I could replicate this behavior through javascript.

Comment: Your browser is not listening to events, it's dispatching it. So whatever your bug is, there is very little chance that you dispatching a js event would change anything. However, we stackoverflow community, can help gou better debug **that** bug. But you'll need to provide enough information about it of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you change the browser with `onresize` event is fired and you can listen to it as follows

1. Using JavaScript

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
  let width = document.body.clientWidth;
  let height = document.body.clientHeight;
  console.log(width, height);
})
```

2. Using Jquery

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log('window was resized');
});
```

> Check this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) doc on `resize` event for more information

Hope this helps